# How add extra links in PHP (CSS & Jquery) Video.js WordPress Plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, video.js

Php Code Before

```
if($options['videojs_cdn'] == 'on') { //use the cdn hosted version
    wp_register_style( 'videojs', plugins_url('jw/video-js.css' , __FILE__ ) );
    wp_register_script( 'videojs', plugins_url( 'jw/video.min.js' , __FILE__ ) );
```

Now I have add `jw/jwplayer.css`, `resume/dist/videojs-resume.min.css` and `dist/videojs-resume.min.js`but none of the ones I added did work! This is a WordPress Plugin? how i can fix this?

```
if($options['videojs_cdn'] == 'on') { //use the cdn hosted version
    wp_register_style( 'videojs', plugins_url('jw/video-js.css' , __FILE__ ) );
    wp_register_style( 'videojs', plugins_url( 'jw/jwplayer.css' , __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'videojs' );
    wp_register_style( 'videojs', plugins_url( 'resume/dist/videojs-resume.min.css' , __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'videojs' );

    wp_register_script( 'videojs', plugins_url( 'jw/video.min.js' , __FILE__ ) );
    wp_register_script( 'videojs', plugins_url( 'dist/videojs-resume.min.js' , __FILE__ ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have conflicting handles, each file you register or enqueue with [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) and [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) needs its own handle.

As an aside, you don't need to register and *then* enqueue unless you're using more advanced functionality, typically for simple CSS and JS loading, you can replace all the `register` functions with `enqueue` as long as they have unique handles.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'videojs', plugins_url('jw/video-js.css' , __FILE__ ) );
wp_enqueue_style( 'jwplayer', plugins_url( 'jw/jwplayer.css' , __FILE__ ) );
wp_enqueue_style( 'videojs-resume', plugins_url( 'resume/dist/videojs-resume.min.css' , __FILE__ ) );

wp_enqueue_script( 'videojs', plugins_url( 'jw/video.min.js' , __FILE__ ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'videojs-resume', plugins_url( 'dist/videojs-resume.min.js' , __FILE__ ) );
```

Comment: please, if you have time, take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50204666/change-functions-if-postsubmit-in-if-the-link-exists